# Terminology used in normal probability plots

Tags: normal-distribution, terminology

I'm vaguely familiar with normal probability plots (non-statistician who knows enough to get by). The graph in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150413043919/http://www.public.iastate.edu:80/%7Ewrstephe/stat403/probplot.html):

What are the two dotted curves called, what do they signify, and how are they calculated?

[image]
<sub>(source: [wrstephe at www.public.iastate.edu](https://www.public.iastate.edu/%7Ewrstephe/stat403/plotnorm.gif))</sub>

**edit:** My question is software-independent. I just want to know what side bands used in a typical normal probability plot are called and how they are defined.

---

I don't have a good answer but after stabbing around in the dark on Google I finally found this lecture notes on quantile-quantile plots:

[https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/787/lectures-quantiles2-handouts.pdf](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Eihaka/787/lectures-quantiles2-handouts.pdf)

Comment: My guess is they're intended to be bands within which 95% of the QQ plot points should lie, if the normal assumption were true. Without knowing exactly how Minitab implements its plots, I can't say for certain what they represent.

Comment: Thanks... I don't really care what Minitab does. I don't use it; I have access to Python + NumPy + SciPy. I've seen these types of plots with side bands before and I just want to know what they are in a mathematical sense. You're saying they're 95% bands? What does that mean, quantitatively? (and how do I calculate the curve values myself?)

Comment: You can't generalize with certainty. If you show a plot from program A and think you're also getting an answer that relates to program B, *unless they both explicitly state what they're actually plotting* (or you run a bunch of examples to check), there's a fair chance they're not actually the same thing. So you can say "I don't care what Minitab does" -- well why link to an article that's explicitly discussing Minitab? I've seen this problem a bunch of times with other kinds of display. You *have* to check, because there's a good chance they don't all plot the same thing. ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... Second, I *don't* say "they are 95% bands". First, note that I said "guess" -- and that's what it is. Second, I defined what I meant in what I did guess fairly precisely already. If you have  Python + NumPy + SciPy and care what they have, can't you look at the source code to see what *they* do?

Comment: I don't care about *either* program, I want to know about the statistics and the math. I want to know about the 95% bands. I can figure out how to implement these myself once I know what they are.

Comment: Let me rephrase: I'm going to assume you're correct in guessing they are 95% bands. What does that mean, quantitatively? (and how do I calculate the curve values myself?) I do not have a strong statistics background and I do not know where to look up more information on this subject.

Comment: It depends on what they are _exactly_, e.g. do you want simultaneous or pointwise bands? The method used in creating them can also matter. I like to create such bands using resampling, but the ones you show are too regular for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Ross Ihaka is discussing is (as he explains) *a simultaneous confidence band for the points in the QQ-plot based on a Komogorov-Smirnov interval for $F$*; a point falling outside the band would correspond to rejection by the KS-test.

However, note that the bound from the KS-test is predicated on $\mu$ and $\sigma$ being known. The existence of some value for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ laying within the bands is equivalent to estimating those quantities (whence the test is no longer distribution free, and the bounds too wide -- for which then values from a [Lilliefors test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test) would be necessary).

So if Ihaka is actually doing what he says, the interval would be too wide to be interpreted as a CI with the claimed coverage.

What Ihaka discusses there may or may not be the same thing as what's in the plot you show in your question.